# Query and set ulimit through <demo>.service file in Linux (systemd)

Tags: linux, service, systemd, ulimit

I am working on a project that needs to manage the ulimit through custom services file (lets say demo.service) on Linux.

I need to add a mechanism where my custom services file should attempt to set the current file descriptor to:

`max( current_limit, min(hard_limit, 10240) )`

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the docs for `LimitNOFILE=` in `man systemd.exec`. It allows setting the number of file descriptors for a service.

Comment: That's true but that would need to be a hard coded value. As the original query says, i need to perform a comparative analysis and then do the same. Is it possible?